# How to configure a custom kiosk-enabled app from Google Admin (App Management)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-admin-sdk

I have some "Single app Chrome kiosk device management license" and I want to set a url remotely (from Google Admin) for each OU.

When using Chrome Sign Builder, it is easy, there is a "configure" button :

[image]

But now I built my App using Chrome App Builder and there is no way to have those "environment variables" through the json config file (the button "configure" is not there) :

[image]

How to show this "configure" button?

EDIT : https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6137033?hl=en "If a Chrome app supports a config file, you can upload a config file to customize the app." -> So I guess It is definitely doable, but I can't find how

EDIT 2:
Admin Google did an interface update, so for those:
[image: new interface]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [managed storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/storage)

Add this into manifest.json

```
"storage": {
  "managed_schema": "schema.json"
}
```

example of schema.json :

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "defaultUrl": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Now you have the button, and you are able to upload a configuration file like this one :

```
{
  "defaultUrl": {
     "Value": "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
  }
}
```

And in your code, you can get it like this :

```
chrome.storage.managed.get('defaultUrl', function (data) {
  //data.defaultUrl
});
```